# How can I get ga:sessions from google analytics without having to sign?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm just trying to get a session count to display on my website. I'm using firebase on the site as well.

I've implemented the basic reporting version (V4) in the docs below but it asks me to sign into my account from the client.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

If I'm using firebase and google cloud functions and do all the config setup already in index.html can I get access to google analytics data without having to sign in from the client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the quickstart you're referring describes the basic app that accesses analytics on behalf of the app user. So this doesn't work for your goal of displaying the number of sessions. You need to provide your own credentials for accessing your specific analytics account. Consider using another way to authorise your request to Google Analytics Reporting API https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization